# Inline video.js video play iPhone

Tags: nginx, streaming, video.js, live

Hey guys hope all well...
I need this code to play inline on iPhone

```
<iframe width="560" height="300" src="https://yeco.online/VideoPlayer/mix54fm" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What do I do here where do I add the variable for inline and what is the varible for inline?

Thx!
David

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `playsinline` on the `<video>` element *inside* the iframe.

Comment: Like this:  <iframe width= 100% height="600" src="https://yeco.online/VideoPlayer/streamurmedia" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen playsinline></iframe>

Comment: No, `playsinline` is not an `<iframe>` attribute. It needs to be on the `<video>` element within the iframe.

Comment: I just needed clarification that!  LOL   Thanks so much for the info

Comment: Is this correct???  

<video id="videojs" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" playsinline>

        <source src="https://yeco.online:19360/djivan/djivan.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
       </p>
      
      
     </video>